# How to create an object and assign it to a strictly typed variable?

Tags: typescript

```
form: Insured: {
    firstName: response.primaryInsured.firstName,
    lastName: response.primaryInsured.lastName,
    dateofbirth: response.primaryInsured.dateOfBirth,
}
```

Form is part of an object, and it takes a type of Insured. The syntax here is wrong? How do I assign this new object to form?

Here is my C# equivalent I'm trying to make

```
form = new Insured {
    FirstName = response.FirstName,
    LastName = response.LastName
};
```

Comment: How is `Insured` defined/declared?

Comment: It's a model. I export interface Insured {...}

Comment: Okay, so the first part of my answer applies. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the type when you declare the variable, which you haven't shown. For instance:

```
let form: Insured;
```

Then when assigning the object to it, if `Insured` is just a *type* (and you've now confirmed it is),  you don't include a type at all on the assignment:

```
form = {
    firstName: response.primaryInsured.firstName,
    lastName: response.primaryInsured.lastName,
    dateofbirth: response.primaryInsured.dateOfBirth,
};
```

You can combine those:

```
let form: Insured = {
    firstName: response.primaryInsured.firstName,
    lastName: response.primaryInsured.lastName,
    dateofbirth: response.primaryInsured.dateOfBirth,
};
```

<s>If `Insured` is a class constructor, you'd do:</s>

```
form = new Insured(/*...arguments here...*/);
```

...where `/*...arguments here...*/` depends on how the constructor is written. If it's written to accept the arguments in the order you've shown, then:

```
form = new Insured(
    response.primaryInsured.firstName,
    response.primaryInsured.lastName,
    response.primaryInsured.dateOfBirth,
);
```

And again, you can combine those, in which case you don't need to specify the type, TypeScript will infer it:

```
let form = new Insured(/*...arguments here...*/);
// or to be explicit
let form: Insured = new Insured(/*...arguments here...*/);
```

*(you've now confirmed it's a type, not a class)*